# Camel AWS Cloudwatch Route (aws-cw)

Tags: apache-camel, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to get a camel route integrated with aws cloud watch. My current route looks like this:

```
    from("direct:cloudwatch")
            .setHeader("CamelAwsCwMetricDimensionName", constant(cloudwatchDimensionName))
            .setHeader("CamelAwsCwMetricDimensions", constant(cloudwatchDimensionValue))
            .to("aws-cw://rcg/aws-cw?accessKey=XXX&secretKey=XXX" +
                    "&name={{cloudwatch.metric.name}}" +
                    "&value={{cloudwatch.metric.value}}" +
                    "&unit={{cloudwatch.metric.unit}}");
```

However, I'm getting an "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AmazonCwClient must be specified" exception.
The official page (http://camel.apache.org/aws-cw.html) doesn't have a lot of current examples (new AmazonCloudWatchClient(awsCredentials, clientConfiguration) is deprecated.

Does anyone have any examples on how to get this working? Do I need to load/add the cloud watch client into the camel context?

Thank you.

Comment: Check the unit tests of camel-aws and see how these tests are written

Comment: And the up to date documentation is here: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-aws/src/main/docs/aws-cw-component.adoc

Comment: running the CwComponentIntegrationTest I am getting the same error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AmazonCwClient must be specified

I have replaced the tokens with my personal AWS tokens.

Comment: anyone any thoughts? does anyone have a working example for camel & cloudwatch using the dsl?